# sometimes my file just freezes in my vi |vim, what happened?

Tags: unix

Sometimes when I edit my file using vi or vim, my file just freezes. Even if I type <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, it still freezes there. I `kill -9 <pid>` from another terminal, the pid is killed, but the file still freezes there.

I guess I must have typed some combination of key which I do not know. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 673):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> is probably the culprit; it stops your screen output in most terminals.  As Michael mentioned, you can restore your screen to normal by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Theoretically, setting `stty -ixon` should prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> from freezing your screen, but it's not working on my local Solaris 10 login.

Comment: @CallMeNorm - this also happens with the dastardly <Ctrl-A> shortcut for screen/tmux/etc because I have fat fingers. ;)

Comment: If, for whatever reason -- you globally remapped ("inactivated") Ctrl-Q (e.g. to avoid accidentally quitting Firefox), adding `stty -ixon` to your `~/.bashrc` enables Ctrl-q in terminals. In my case, Ctrl-s was freezing Vim and I could not get back to it ... until I made that .bashrc modification.  Details here: https://superuser.com/a/1328326/409327

Comment: In case this isn't working for anyone, make sure you're entering it correctly: For me `Ctrl-Q` had to be entered as `Ctrl+q`, meaning "press the Ctrl and lowercase q keys simultaneously."   Maybe `Ctrl+Q` (press Ctrl and uppercase Q simultaneously) would work, but in Terminal (Ubuntu), that is mapped to quit Terminal.

Answer (score 84):

<s>Do you happen to use it inside GNU Screen?</s> (As pra points out, this is apparently true even outside screen) It's pretty common to accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> (`xoff`), which disables screen painting until you hit <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> (`xon`)

Comment: is there any key which will freeze the file if my vim is combined with cscope?

Comment: it happens(sometimes) after I types shift+insert, and vi shows: open mode.

Comment: Ctr-S is not specific to GNU screen.

Answer (score 2):

**If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> isn't your problem (as in [pra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419820/sometimes-my-file-just-freezes-in-my-vi-vim-what-happened/3432409#3432409)) this may help you.**

If you've tried to install a bunch of custom plugins using **Vundle**, sometimes things go awry. You can try to remove these packages manually and see if it helps. Find out where the plugins have been written to - in my case they were all inside the `.vim/bundle` directory because I used `git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` to install **Vundle**. So once inside the `.vim` directory you can wipe the entire bundle folder to remove all plugins, and start again, by executing `rm -rf bundle`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -16):

You can try to change keyboard layout. Vi|vim interacts with English(-like?) input only.