# How do I insert ERB-tags with Vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

How do I insert `<% %>` in Vim? I have rails.vim.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've been using the [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin for a long time, but not the [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) plugin. Turns out that the rails.vim plugin is adding functionality to surround.vim, or is piggy-backing on it. Either way, I got it working this-a way:

1. Install the rails.vim plugin if it isn't already, and open an ERB document. Vim should recognize it as a `eruby` filetype.
2. If it doesn't use `:set filetype=eruby` <kbd>Return</kbd> to make Vim see things your way.
3. Visually select some text you want to wrap with the ERB tags using <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>. (That's capital S)
5. The selected text should be wrapped in a `<%= %>` or `<%- %>` block.

I just confirmed this works in column-selection mode too.

This is documented in the rails.vim help: from the command-mode search for `:h rails-surround`. And if you don't have the help available for rails.vim, it's because the instructions weren't followed for installing it:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

The rails.vim plugin *requires* the surround.vim plugin also, so that has to be previously installed. I use that plugin's functionality at least once a minute when I'm editing. It rocks.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the intro but I do know vim :-) I was looking for a shortcut. Does anyone else know? I can't imagine that rails.vim doesn't have it - I just can't find any documentation for it anywhere.

Comment: The visual mode shortcut has changed from s to S

Answer (score 71):

It is also possible to insert erb tags in INSERT mode (using rails.vim and surround.vim plugins):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> afterwards to insert `<%= %>` block
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> afterwards to insert `<% -%>` block
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> afterwards to insert `<%# %>` block

Comment: I just saw also that Ctrl + s, Ctrl + s, = will result in a new ERB tag being opened up for a multiline add, at least with my current configuration. As expected, you can do this for the - and # as well.

Comment: In terminal vim the mapping is `ctrl+g` `s` followed by the surround key.

Comment: Further to Anthony's comment: <C-s> <C-e> (in INSERT mode) will put in a <% * %><% end %> pair (on separate lines with * denoting cursor position).

Comment: Warning: Ctrl+s can result in this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419820/sometimes-my-file-just-freezes-in-my-vi-vim-what-happened

Comment: I'm using http://vim-bootstrap.com/ and, in my case, in insert mode the trigger was capital S instead.

Answer (score 15):

For surroundings in the `erb` views you might need Tim Pope's [ragtag](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag). It can handle different `erb` specific surroundings. Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag/raw/master/doc/ragtag.txt).

Comment: I can second this answer, you will need `vim-rails`, `vim-surround` and `vim-ragtag`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in vimrc: (no plugin needed)

```
iabbrev erb <%%><Left><Left>
```

If you type `erb=` in insert mode, you will get `<%=%>` with the cursor after the `=`.
Or just `erb<space>` to get `<% %>`.
You can replace this with any abbreviation you like.
This is not shorter then just typing `<%`, but I find it easier and faster.