# how to exclude dash sign (-) from erb tags <% -%> when using rails.vim and surround vim plugins

Tags: vim

I use rails.vim and surround.vim plugins to insert <% -%> tags as explained in this topic [How do I insert ERB-tags with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275209/how-to-insert-erb-tags-with-vim).

How can i remove dash sign from this little "template", because it no longer needed in rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hop over to `rails.vim`:

`mvim ~/.vim/autoload/rails.vim`

and remove hyphen in the following line:

`call self.setvar('surround_45', "<% \r -%>")`

Now `yss-` will wrap code in line with `<% %>`.

You will probably want to do the same with the `end`-shortcuts — see [this diff](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/commit/4eca304a673396eb41106464a9b1c6f37fe1aea9) for the details *(it was commited two days ago)*.

Comment: i did that myself earlier, just forgot to update the question, anyway thanks for the clear solution.